# Printing color characters in string variable with Python 2.7

Tags: python, unicode, colors, ansi-colors

The topic seems to have been discussed to death on SO, still I can't for the life of me manage to render a simple string with ANSI color characters. Obviously the following works fine, the site name appears in green on my terminal:

```
>>> print u'I love \u001b[0;32mStack Overflow\u001b[0m'
I love Stack Overflow
```

However:

```
>>> test='I love \u001b[0;32mStack Overflow\u001b[0m'

>>> test
'I love \\u001b[0;32mStack Overflow\\u001b[0m'

>>> print test
I love \u001b[0;32mStack Overflow\u001b[0m

>>> print test.encode('utf8')
I love \u001b[0;32mStack Overflow\u001b[0m

>>> print test.decode('utf8')
I love \u001b[0;32mStack Overflow\u001b[0m

>>> print unicode(test, 'utf8')
I love \u001b[0;32mStack Overflow\u001b[0m
```

What the hell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print colored text in terminal in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-in-terminal-in-python)

Comment: I saw that in my Python 2 version, \u001b[0m doesn't work, why?

Answer (score 1):

Define it as a Unicode string:

```
 test = u'I love \u001b[0;32mStack Overflow\u001b[0m'
```

This way it will print correctly:

```
>>> print test
I love Stack Overflow
```

Comment: I would if I could but I can't. I get the variable as is.

Comment: @chris_here: do you understand the difference between `u'\u0021'` and `u'\\u0021'`? Update your question and include the *actual* value (run `print repr(your_variable)`).

Answer (score 1):

If you are receiving Unicode escapes in byte string, decode it:

```
>>> test='I love \u001b[0;32mStack Overflow\u001b[0m'
>>> test
'I love \\u001b[0;32mStack Overflow\\u001b[0m'
>>> test.decode('unicode_escape')
u'I love \x1b[0;32mStack Overflow\x1b[0m'
>>> print(test.decode('unicode_escape'))
I love Stack Overflow
```

Comment: Ok that's exactly what I was after, thanks a lot. I think the confusion stemmed from the fact that using ASCII chars \033 or \x1b works readily but \u001b does not.

Comment: If you get a byte string with the individual characters for \033 or \x1b (4 bytes each) you'd still have to decode them, though.